# Pushing elements downwards when certain elements exist

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

I have some markup for a set of fields within a form:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Field label</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <input type="text" value="a" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <input type="text" value="b" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <input type="text" value="c" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And some CSS to position them:

```
*{
    position: relative;
}

span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

input{
    float:left;
}

label{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    left: 70px;
}

li > ul{
    margin-left: -100px;
    max-width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}


li > label{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This results in this layout, which is perfect for what I need:
[image]

Problem: The system generates error messages when certain fields are filled in incorrectly, resulting in markup like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Field label</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <div class="error">some error message.</div>
                <input type="text" value="a" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <div class="error">some error message.</div>
                <input type="text" value="b" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <label>some label</label>
                <div class="error">some error message.</div>
                <input type="text" value="c" size="35" maxlength="35">
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This results in something like this:

[image]

Instead, I would like the error messages to show up like this:

[image]

I have tried making the label within the span to be positioned absolutely and then aligned to the bottom of the span. However, for some reason, it is always being overlapped by the text input even if I give the label a `margin-top`.

How can I get the form to look like the desired layout when error messages are inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the label consistently show underneath the text input, whether or not the error message is present, I would suggest the following approach:

1. Position the label at the bottom of the span.
2. Add margin to the bottom of the input, to grow the span large enough to contain the label.

Here is a reduced example to illustrate the technique:

HTML:

```
  <span>
      <label>some label</label>
      <div class="error">some error message.</div>
      <input type="text" value="a" size="35" maxlength="35">
  </span>
```

CSS:

```
span{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuEqB/

Answer (score 0):

Just use float left and rearrange the elements in the html:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: block;
}

.form-label {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

ul ul {
    float: left;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ysv8E/embedded/result/

Comment: Unfortunately, as the HTML is generated by the backend, I do not have any freedom to rearrange them :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm reading this correctly, but...

margin-top won't work on an isolated element with position:absolute, because absolutely-positioned elements aren't a part of the regular flow layout. The top margin has nothing to act against.

The elements with position:absolute also will not cause extra vertical space to be used in the regular flow layout, which is why they're appearing over the input instead of below it.

If you must use position:absolute, you'll have to arrange another way for extra vertical space to be added to the layout. Using CSS, you could hide and show invisible elements that do not have position:absolute (in addition to hiding and showing the error messages), or you could increase the margin or padding between each form element while the error message is showing. But there's probably a simpler way to do it (with less use of absolute position).